# Uploading image to Amazon AWS S3 and then sending to Mobile App developed using React Native

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, expo

I have a scenario in which there are many users using my mobile app. The mobile app is being developed using React Native expo.

Suppose I upload an image on my Amazon AWS S3 bucket. I then want this image to be sent to a particular user (single user) **automatically**. How can I achieve this?

I think I would also need to maintain a database containing unique ID of each user? And then somehow use this information to send the above image to a particular user. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways we can achieve this, here is a common pattern

- When uploading an image to S3, we could add additional metadata. so, we could add metadata saying to whom images should be sent to.

Ex: userEmail

```
   s3.upload({
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: key,
      Body: fileStream,
      Metadata: {
        userEmail: "testuser@yahoo.com",
      },
    }).promise();
```

Above code will send x-amz-meta-* header

[image]

- Now we can enable S3 [event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) to trigger a Lambda function, where you can index the details to DynamoDb table and do other necessary things.